# Clear a field of an existing record while accessing the form

Tags: grails, groovy

When accessing a form I need to add a field that has to be empty even if in the backend it has value. And when the user enters a value in this field, this newly entered value should replace the old one when the form is submitted.

The code below presents my best attempt, but `onload` doesn't do anything here for some reason. On the other hand if I use `onclick` the value is cleared as soon as the field is clicked. Could you please point me to right direction on what I am doing wrong with `onload` or if there's alternative solution to achieve the same need?

```
<g:textField 
   class="internal-text" 
   name="Internal__c" 
   value="${Instance?.Internal__c}" 
   onload="if (this.value != '') {this.value = '';}" 
   maxlength="20"/>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why are we doing your homework for you?

Comment: @BurtBeckwith - I don't think I was asking anyone to do my work. I am really sorry if I made it look like that and made you feel like I am taking the advantage of this great community.  
After trying the best I can, I got stuck on something which I had no experience or point of reference with before and requested for community's help. Didn't know textField tag don't work with onload event as Vimm kindly pointed out below. Let me know what I did wrong and I promise I'll correct it next time I interact with the community.

Comment: I read "Working on my first grails assignment" as a homework assignment, but it certainly could be a work assignment I suppose :)

Comment: @BurtBeckWith - It was indeed a work assignment. Going back to school soon though. But that's another chapter.I would be careful not to irritate you again :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest adding a hidden field and use a dummy text field to set it.  The text field can be blank as desired, and when it changes you copy the value to the hidden field.

```
<g:hiddenField name="Internal__c" value="${Instance?.Internal__c}" />
<g:textField class="internal-text" name="Internal__c_dummy" onchange="this.form.elements['Internal__c'].value = this.value" maxlength="20" />
```

Comment: Not all tags have onload events, and the input tag is one of them.